# Importing methods that return data in Vue/Vuetify 3 and updating tables axios

Tags: vue.js, methods, import, vuetify.js

Currently using Vuetify 3 I'm trying to get this search method "showBills" to return data to the search page, and then update the search page to display the fetched data.

I have already tested these things and they are working:

- API URI string with search results: returns data when used in a browser
- Method: when written directly as part of the search page before being included in another js file that is imported would populate page with data fetched from API, now that it's exported, will populate an alert with JSON data
- Method import: method is properly called and will pop up alert boxes with dummy text and API returned text when called from another js file

My guess is that it has something to do with the way I'm either rendering/handling page updates or the way that I am returning data from the method

Any insight?

**This is the search page**

```html
<template>
  <v-text-field
    v-model="keywords"
    :loading="loading"
    density="compact"
    clearable
    label="Keyword"
    variant="outlined"
    hint="Keywords are words that might be in the bill"
    prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
    single-line
    hide-details
    @keydown.enter.prevent="$bills = showBills(keywords)"
  ></v-text-field>
  <v-table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-left">BILL ID</th>
        <th class="text-left">BILL NUMBER</th>
        <th class="text-left">TITLE</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="bill in bills" v-bind:key="bill.bill_id">
        <td>{{ bill.bill_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ bill.bill_number }}</td>
        <td>{{ bill.title }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </v-table>
</template>
<script>
import { showBills } from '../dir/file.js'
export default {
  name: 'KeywordResults',
  data() {
    return {
      bills: [],
      keywords: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showBills
  }
}
</script>
```

**This is the method**

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import _ from 'underscore'

export function showBills(keywordString) {
  axios
    .get('api query string', {
      params: {
        key: 'redacted',
        op: 'search',
        state: 'mystate',
        query: keywordString.split().join(',')
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      var bills2 = []
      response = response.data.searchresult
      delete response.summary
      _.each(response, function (value) {
        bills2.push(value)
      })
      //In debugging i put alert(bills2) which worked
      //and the alert window showed "[object, object],[object,object],..."
      return bills2
    })
    .catch(() => {
      this.bills2 = []
    })
}
```

Comment: Of course. If you take a moment to reread the first short paragraph, the functionality is described there! :) Also in the code you can see where the function showBills is linked. I've also listed what I've tried in bullet points. Unfortunately the .then doesn't need to be changed as it's functionality has been working properly and tested multiple times. The issue is with how the two files are passing data to each other and how the vuetify table is then being updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

The external method:

```
export const showBills = (keywords) =>
  axios
    .get('api query string', {
      params: {
        key: 'redacted',
        op: 'search',
        state: 'mystate',
        query: keywords.split().join(',')
      }
    })
    .then(
      ({
        data: {
          searchresult: { summary, ...result }
        }
      }) => Object.values(result)
    )
    .catch(() => [])
```

Usage:

```js
import { showBills } from './path/to/showBills'
export default {
  data: () => ({ bills: [] }),
  methods: {
    async showBills(keywords) {
      this.bills = await showBills(keywords)
    }
  }
}
```

---

Or, with the least amount of changes, place a `return` in front of `axios` in your current function. Also `return []` from `catch`, instead of assigning to an undefined `this.bills2`:

```js
export function showBills(keywordString) {
  return axios
    .get('api query string', {
      params: {
        key: 'redacted',
        op: 'search',
        state: 'mystate',
        query: keywordString.split().join(',')
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      const result = response.data.searchresult
      delete result.summary
      return Object.values(result)
    })
    .catch(() => [])
}
```

The usage of `showBills` remains unchanged (as shown above).

---

Side note: `.split().join(',')` doesn't do anything to any text.

Given `const s = 'Some text'`, `s.split()` returns `['Some text']`, which makes the consequent `.join(',')` useless, as no comma will be added if the input is a an array with a single element. The initial string is sent unchanged to backend.

If it should return `['Some', 'text']`, so that the server receives: `'Some,text'`, you should use `s.split(' ').join(',')` (or, better yet, `s.trim().split(/\s+/).join(',')`, which treats multiple spaces as a single one and also removes any leading or trailing spaces).

Another problem I see in your component is that you initialise `keywords` with an empty array and use it in a `<v-text-field>`'s `v-model`, which expects a `string`. It's possible Vuetify sanitises it behind the scenes, so it works, but `v-model` on a text input should be a `string`.

Last, but not least, I'd call the method `getBills`, not `showBills`, because that's what it does. The template *"shows"* them, as soon as the method populates `this.bills`.

---

Ref: `eslint` complaining about unused vars in destructuring:

1. Read [this](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/4880)
2. Add this to your eslint config:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": ["error", { "ignoreRestSiblings": true }]
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could place this above the offending line:

```js
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
```

Comment: I kind of understand what's going on. I code way more in python and java, so the paradigms in js and vue are a bit over my head. 

Lint is telling me summary is defined but never used. From what i understand, you're creating a function that uses axios to query, and .then to define the data structure, and that's all input for a function that uses ...rest as the input to set generic values for the object

Comment: `const { excluded, ...rest} = object` is done *specifically* for not using `excluded` and, in this case, using `rest`. It's an inline form of `delete object.excluded`. From your code I couldn't deduce what the rest of data is, but I guessed it was an object, not an array, since an array wouldn't have a `.summary` property. And `_.each` is quite flexible, works with both arrays and objects. Anyway, the important bit of the answer is that you need to return the promise (e.g: `axios.get`) and then you can assign it to whatever you want where you're importing it. I'm guessing it worked.

Comment: What I'm doing in `then` is called [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). It's just an arrow function which expects that particular structure and returns [the values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) of `response.data.searchresults`, bar its `summary`. It's more of a suggestion. You can keep your version, provided you return the promise ***and*** return an empty array in `catch`. Your `catch` doesn't work, btw.

Comment: @user3794851,  I added the actual code of how you want to modify the existing `showBills`, if you're not a fan of my proposed syntax. They work the same.

Comment: It didn't work yet because it wants variable to be declared before it is used (even though it is a key in the axios response). However this has been helpful just to see javascript used in a different way

Comment: Okay AMAZING thank you! The revised code worked. I'm unfortunately really struggling in this one specific area of connecting javascript files to one another. To save me from constantly relying on others, do you know of any good docs, tutorials that kind of explain what I was misunderstanding in the code? I can definitely follow what you are doing here!

Comment: In my estimation, you stumbled across one of the most confusing parts of JS: [using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). I whole heartedly recommend MDN's docs for anything web related. They're focused on comprehensibility. Their guides are stellar, as well.

Comment: I just want to say that you've answered everything 100% including future learning, and a thorough explanation of the issue on multiple accounts. This is by far the BEST stack overflow interaction I've ever had. Thank you!